# file path issue with Taurus in Blazemeter

Tags: selenium, pytest, blazemeter, taurus

I have to run my selenium based UAT in blazemeter. I configured the Tauras YAML file as :
execution:
- executor: selenium
  runner: pytest
  iterations: 1
  concurrency: 10
  scenario: simple
scenarios:
  simple:
    script: TestSail.py

I have attached my screenshot from Blazemter as well. My TestSail.py is on the same shared-folder as the YAML file and it depends on other two files. The Tauras file works perfectly on my local test but Blazemeter throughs an error saying testfail.py dont exist. I am confused on how Blazemter handles the files. I would appreciate any inputs here.[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe2iP.png]

Comment: If at all _...confused on how Blazemter handles the files..._ why is `Selenium` tagged?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying the target script as newfile/TestSail.py.